# My script runs once, how do I code it to run always?

Tags: python, notifications, widget, system-tray

I'm new to python and programming in general. I made a small script that gives me a notification when the battery reaches 100% or goes below 25%. It runs fine for a single instance. I'm trying to get it to always run i.e. that it sits in the tray and popups up the notification as per the conditions. I tried putting the whole thing through a "while True:" loop but that does not seem to help. Could you guys help me out?

Code:-

````
import psutil
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toaster=ToastNotifier()
while True:
    def battery():
        val=psutil.sensors_battery()
        percent=val.percent
        power=val.power_plugged
        if percent<25 and power==False:
            return ('We\'re low on power({}%),plug in the charger.'.format(percent))
        elif percent>=100 and power==True:
            return ('Fully charged ({}%),you can disconnect the charger now.'.format(percent))
    try:
        toaster.show_toast('BatteryMeter',battery(),'c:/users/sanoop/desktop/Battery.ico',duration=5)
    except:
        pass```
````

Comment: You're not calling the battery function like you were earlier.

Comment: @stovfl Edited. When I do that it just creates an endless loop of system tray icons even when the condition is not met. When it is met, the same endless loop with notifications. I understand that's expected.

Comment: You don't need to put the function definition inside the while loop, just the function would be enough.

Comment: @sanoop: See the simulation at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SarcasticMidnightblueRatios)

Comment: @stovfl Thanks I'll try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to routinely call the battery() in while, nothing else.
So, for example, considering the rest of your code remains the same:

```
while True:
  battery()
  time.sleep(1)
```